# AWS - API Call - jquery ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax, amazon-web-services

I'm new to AWS. Trying to consume an API in AWS. It's an AJAX request, the response is something like `{“readyState”:0,“responseText”:“”,“status”:0,“statusText”:“error”}`

I'm trying to consume the API from my localhost. As few posts says AWS doesn't allow crossDomain request. How do I test it locally?

```
        var postURL= "http://example.com/user/" + txtMemberId;

        $.ajax({
            url: postURL,
            crossDomain: true,
            datatype: "text",
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(xhr);
            }
        });
```

The status is a (ok=200) and it's a valid response if I directly hit the API by giving URL in the browser

Comment: AWS does allow cross-domain requests. What service is this API running on exactly? AWS API Gateway? EC2? If it's just an app running on an EC2 instance then this becomes an Apache or Nginx question instead of an AWS question. You need to provide more details so that we can give you instructions for enabling CORS.

Comment: @MarkB The application is deployed to Elastic Bean Stalk

Comment: Then you need to enable CORS on the web server running the API on Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: I have enabled CORS for app bucket but still there is no valid response. The CORS definition looks likke:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
<MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
<ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
<ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>
<ExposeHeader>x-amz-id-2</ExposeHeader>
<AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>

Comment: You have to enable CORS on the Elastic Beanstalk server.

Answer (score 1):

1-Sign in to the API Gateway console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway.

2-In the API Gateway console, choose an API under APIs.

3-Choose a resource under Resources. This will enable CORS for all the methods on the resource.

4-Alternatively, you could choose a method under the resource to enable CORS for just this method.

5-Choose Enable CORS from the Actions drop-down menu.

for more information:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

[image]

Comment: He's not using API Gateway.